# conditional transformation on json doc

Tags: json, conditional-statements, iteration, jq

I have the following json doc (file.json):

```
[{
  "mount": "/",
  "size": "45G",
  "usedperc": "26"
},
{
  "mount": "/opt",
  "size": "197G",
  "usedperc": "20"
},
{
  "mount": "/tmp",
  "size": "5.0G",
  "usedperc": "8"
}]
```

Given this doc , I would like to transform into a different doc, with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "key": "val1",
    "mnt": "/-rootFS",
    "key3": {
      "key4": "val4"
    }
  },
 {
    "key": "val1",
    "mnt": "/opt-optFS",
    "key3": {
      "key4": "val4"
    }
  },
 {
    "key": "val1",
    "mnt": "/tmp-tmpFS",
    "key3": {
      "key4": "val4"
    }
  }
]
```

HOwever, when trying to apply the transformation with js, it stops on the first iteration of the document , and does not process the rest of the doc:

```
jq  ' [{
      "key":"val1",
      "mnt": .[]|(if select(.mount == "/") then  "/-rootFS" elif select(.mount == "/opt") then "/opt-optFS" elif select(.mount == "/tmp") then "/tmp-tmpFS" else . end ) ,
      "key3":{
         "key4": "val4"
      }}]' < file.json
```

#output

```
[
  {
    "key": "val1",
    "mnt": "/-rootFS",
    "key3": {
      "key4": "val4"
    }
  }
]
```

Not sure how to do it , I have tried in many different ways, mostly getting a "Cannot index array with string "mount"" error. Btw this is actually just a test case from a bigger jq expression, so I would like to do it with jq if that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
map( (.mount 
      | if . == "/" then "root" 
        elif . == "/opt" then "opt" 
        else "tmp" end) as $type
      | {key: "val1",
         mnt:  "\(.mount)-\($type)FS",
         key3: {key4: "val4"}} )
```

Comment: many thanks! this was the direction I needed